# Additional route causes Home route to stop working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use React Router Dom and It happens that whenever I try to add a second route, it causes the first route `'/'` to stop working but just by removing the route it suddenly works. I tried having multiple routes but it still won't work.

How can I add more routes ?

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import AddProduct from "./pages/AddProduct";


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/add-product" element={<AddProduct />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My navbar looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800 p-4 flex items-center justify-around ">
      <ul className="flex space-x-4 text-white">
        <li>
          <Link to="/" className="hover:text-gray-300">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/add-product" className="hover:text-gray-300">
            Add Product
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Did you try adding ```exact``` to the definition of the Home route?

Comment: @Fatorice Yes I tried it and got the same result

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code at all, it's all completely correct syntax. As-is I don't see any reproducible issue here. Are there any errors on the browser console? Perhaps there is an issue in the `AddProduct` component when it is added to the routes. See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the problem that we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

Try your path like this :

```
<Route path="/add-product" element={<AddProduct />} />
```

Answer (score -1):

The path should start with a forward slash ("/") to correctly match the URL.

```
<Route path="/add-product" element={<AddProduct />} />
```

Comment: I think you can instead nest the `add-product` Route within the `/` Route as a child element.  See [this example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/30917ae5ea7551225c9bdb3852ee5ccde2360569/examples/basic/src/App.tsx#L20):

Comment: The leading `"/"` is implied and not necessary/required, all routes are assumed relative from root, e.g. from `"/"`.